# Keycloak JAX-RS and Postman Authorization (Auth URL)

Tags: oauth-2.0, jax-rs, token, postman, keycloak

I have resources with jax-rs and use keycloak 
I want to get the token with Postman

this is the database client for jax-rs (keycloak-quickstart)

```
{
  "realm": "demo",
  "bearer-only": true,
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "database-service"
}
```

I created a client for Postman

```
{
  "realm": "demo",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "client-postman",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "b53f32d3-e15b-474b-a88d-1f1cfa68c2dc"
  }
}
```

I chose the OAuth 2.0 type
[image]

The url for the access token is

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

But I do not know what the **auth url** is
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i know how to get the token by code, i do not know how to do via postman

Comment: The post I linked to explains it using `curl` but it's the same idea.  To call your service you need a `Authorization` header.  Don't forget the `Bearer` part.

Comment: When I try to get the token I get it {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client requires user consent"}

Comment: Just disable it **Consent Required : OFF**

Comment: thanks @stdunbar Everything works perfectly with both url and postman but you know the auth url to insert it into the token request in Postman so you can speed up

Comment: for spring users, the clientID in Postman is the resource in the.yaml file

Answer (score 29):

with current version of Postman and keycloak `2.2.1.Final` i've managed to setup OAuth 2.0

[image: Postman setup for keycloak]

Client Secret: not required but AFAIK you cane have it setup in client and then you have to provide it here

Auth Url: `https://{KEYCLOAK}/auth/realms/{REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/auth`

Token Url: `https://{KEYCLOAK}/auth/realms/{REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token`

You can get those urls from 
`https://{KEYCLOAK}/auth/realms/{REALM}/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Comment: Superior answer. Works like a charm!

Comment: Just in case it helps anybody. In my case I also needed to provide a scope but my realm configuration might be different.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to receive the token but I do not know how to call the jax-rs resources

I set it in keycloak:

```
Direct Access Grants Enabled: ON
Service Accounts Enabled : ON
```

[image]

and the postman request
[image]

Now that I have the token I can call resources by setting the jaxrs url and in the header **Authorization: bearer [my token]**

[image]

Now I would like to use Postman's Authorization function to speed up the steps and call resources directly, but I do not know if it's possible

Comment: @ShubhamJain I did not understand the question

Comment: My application is get auth token from key clock .. due to which I m stuck on login itself in postman tests as postman do not allow to import additional packages .. How you handle this situation

Comment: Hi @Pako .. I have raised a question regarding same .. please review and let me know if you have any workaround regarding same .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48146410/unable-to-get-token-from-keycloak