# unable to get oauth token from Keycloak

Tags: postman, keycloak

I have an application which is getting Auth from Keycloak.

My Access Type is public so I do not have any client secret.

I have given access to "**Direct Access Grants Enabled**" as **ON**

Refer below:

[image]

I am getting error from postman as below:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
}
```

Note : My credentials is right as I am using same to login on keycloak

I have also check the key and they seems correct as per below reference:

https://gist.github.com/rac021/623e4f4c87069acd0c38d952568f8a3d

while I have setup as per my understanding.

References:

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if I missing anything or you need any more details.

Any workaround will be appreciated !!!!

Comment: Below article also help me on same : http://xpam.pl/blog/?p=154

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error message `"Invalid user credentials"` is reliable. That is, you either specified a wrong username or password.
Check that the user really exists in the realm you are addressing with the URL. Particularly if it is not the *master* realm which usually will be used to login to keycloak admin console.

Comment: Yes ... you are right I was trying with login user .. Thanks for help

Comment: It could also be that you are attempting to login using the wrong flow/grant. That's what I experienced. I was trying PKCE but Keycloak was configured to expect `Client Authentication`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.
Mine was due the the OTP (optional) in the direct grant Flow

Answer (score 4):

For LDAP users I am getting this issue. With some user able to login with Authorization code flow, but when I am using the same user to get access token from postman with token URL getting below response.

{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
}

To fix the above error I removed required user actions for the user and enabled email verified option.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error response in the postman, because I didn't added the role to client, which then must be added to user roles :

[1) Create client role.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVyeu.png)

[2) Add this role to user roles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgbMF.png)

[3) then token from postman was obtained without this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZbDJ.png)

Comment: It helped for me. I created a role for client-adapter(clients) and then I added the role for my user.

Answer (score 1):

It was happening only in Postman, I reset the user password and back to work normaly

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that export/import process was not including users, please check twice if u have them in your admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. **Just swich to required realm** and try to create user in it.

Don't forget to add role to this user.

[image: change realm keyCloak]